# Prove the lower bound of the function $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m} x_i\log{x_i}$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i =1$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization

Can anyone prove the lower bound of the function $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m} x_i\log{x_i}$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i =1$, thanks!

The lower bound is given as $f(x)\ge-\log{m}$, but why?

Comment: *Hint:* Apply the Jensen's inequality using the convex function $x\mapsto x\log x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\log$ is concave, Jensen's inequality yields

$$\sum_{i=1}^m x_i \log\left({\frac{1}{x_i}}\right) ≤ \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i \cdot \frac{1}{x_i}\right) = \log m$$

This inequality is sharp because equality is attained when $x_1 = \cdots = x_m = 1/m$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $i\ne j$ and $x_i>x_j.$ For $y\in [0,x_i-x_j]$ let $g(y)=(x_i-y)\ln (x_i-y)+(x_j+y)\ln (x_j+y).$ Then $g'(0)<0.$ So for some (sufficiently small) $y_1\in (0,x_i-x_j)$ we have $g(y_1)<g(0).$

So, in the expression for $f,$ if we replace $x_i,x_j$ with $x_i-y_1,x_j+y_1,$ we get a lower value for $f$. So $f$ is not minimized if some $x_i>x_j.$

So (i)$\,\min f$ exists,and (ii) $\,\min f$ does not occur if any two $x_i,x_j$ are unequal. Therefore $\min f$ occurs when and only when every $x_i=1/m.$

Comment: This answer is inspiring, though it does not answer my question in a straightforward way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Lagrange multipliers, consider
$$F= \sum_{i = 1}^{m} x_i\log(x_i)+\lambda\sum_{i = 1}^{m} x_i$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}=1+\lambda+\log(x_i)=0$$ So, all $x_i$ are equal and then $x_i=\frac 1m$

Comment: This proof seems trivial

Comment: @Harry_Cai. For sure, it is !

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i>0$, then $$f(x)=x \ln x \implies f''(x)=1/x>0$$ so according to Jensens inequality $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \ln x_i}{n} \ge \bar x \log \bar x=-\frac{\ln n}{n}$$ $$  \bar x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=\frac{1}{n},~\text{given}~\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=1$$.
Finally, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \ln x_i \ge -\ln n$$

Comment: On understanding Jensen's Inequality: In the words of W.W.Sawyer, if $f''>0$ then the graph of $f$ holds water. In other words, if $f''>0$ then $S=\{(x,y): y\ge f(x)\}$ is a convex set, so $\,(\,n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i,\;n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\,)\in S.$

Comment: Why does the first inequality hold? Jensen tells us $tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) \ge f(tx+(1-t)y)$ for convex function f, where $t+(1-t) = 1$. However, $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n}$ does not sum up to 1.